# ScrollBar showing up in WebBrowser when page loads

Tags: c#, html, wpf, iframe, webbrowser-control

Edit: I changed the property to Hidden, but it still shows up.

I have read about 10 different variations of this problem and all of them seem to have a different solution none of which work for me.

I have a WPF Window with a WebBrowser as shown below (as you can see I have been very thorough in trying to make sure the vertical scroll bar is hidden):

```
<Window x:Class="ZendeskWebApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="460" Width="700" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <WebBrowser Name="_browser" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the code behind I am loading a local html page:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this._browser.Source = new Uri(new System.IO.FileInfo("AskAQuestion.htm").FullName);
}
```

This is the only content on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ask A Question</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <iframe src="http://mysite.zendesk.com/account/dropboxes/123456" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></iframe>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The only scrollbar that should be showing up is the iframe scrollbar, yet a vertical scrollbar loads whenever the page loads in the iframe. When there is no page loaded there is no scrollbar.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just a thought but probably because the page your are loading is longer than the MaxHeight of your WebBrowser control?

Comment: If I have the VerticalScrollBar disabled I thought it should never show up even if the page height is longer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this combination of settings on your WebBrowser object?

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```

Comment: that is pretty much how microsoft says it should be/work for what you want to do... therefore i would say that there is a section in your code where the browser settings change?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

XAML:

```
<WebBrowser Name="MyWebBrowser" LoadCompleted="WebBrowserOnLoadCompleted">
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void WebBrowserOnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HideScrollbars(MyWebBrowser);
}

private void HideScrollbars(WebBrowser wb)
{
    const string script = "document.body.style.overflow ='hidden'";
    wb.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] { script, "JavaScript" });
}
```